# C# - Mouse Down event for form is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make draggable window form, but when I tried to detect mouse down and up event to form, but event does not fire.
Other things seems working but those 2 events are not.

```
public form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
    this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;

    Debug.Write("initialized");
}

private void form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("dragging..");
}

private void form_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("drag done");
}
```

Comment: You made the form transparent, makes it also transparent to the mouse.  You can take advantage of a bug in Windows that's been around too long to be fixed.  Edit to this.BackColor = Color.Red;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to add a `panel` to your form and set `Dock` to `top` in order to cover the title bar area. then use this sample code

```
private bool isDragging = false;
private Point lastLocation;

private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    lastLocation = e.Location;
}

private void panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(
        (this.Location.X - lastLocation.X) + e.X, 
        (this.Location.Y - lastLocation.Y) + e.Y);

        this.Update();
    }
 }

 private void panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    isDragging = false;
 }
```

don't forget to add handlers in the form constructor

```
panel.MouseDown += panel_MouseDown;
panel.MouseMove += panel_MouseMove;
panel.MouseUp += panel_MouseUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for form, register those methods your using to listen for the mouse down events like this.

```
public form() { 
 InitializeComponent(); 
 this.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia; 
 this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor; 
 Debug.Write("initialized");
 //register the methods to listen for the events
 this.MouseDown += form_MouseDown;
 this.MouseUp += form_MouseUp;
 }
 private void form_MouseDown(object sender, 
  MouseEventArgs e) { 

   Debug.Write("dragging.."); 

} 
 private void form_MouseUp(object sender, 
 MouseEventArgs e) { 

   Debug.Write("drag done");
 }
```